# What is my volume?

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Given an input integer, output the volume corresponding to the value. The value will always be in the range \$[0,100]\$.

### Examples

If the input \$=0\$:

```
 _/|
|  |\/
|_ |/\
  \|
```

If the input \$>0\$ and \$<33\$:

```
 _/|
|  |\
|_ |/
  \|
```

If the input \$\ge33\$ and \$<66\$:

```
 _/| \
|  |\ \
|_ |/ /
  \| /
```

If the input \$\ge66\$, \$\le100\$:

```
 _/| \ \
|  |\ \ \
|_ |/ / /
  \| / /
```

### Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- Any amount of extraneous whitespace is permitted, provided the characters line up appropriately.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: You should have based the volume on 0 - 10 so that someone could answer with "mine goes to 11"

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), 98 bytes

```javascript
n=>` _/|2
|  |\\0
|_ |/1
  \\|3`.replace(/\d/g,k=>n?(k&1?' /':' \\').repeat(n/33^n>98):['/\\'[k]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcoxDoIwFADQvaf4k@2PSgtNiJIAB6EIDRaikJYAcerdK44OzO@99Uev3fKat6t1TxP6PNi8aKHhPiEewCsliG/A85gAKOVlGy1mnnRnGFdPPlzGvLAlG09xSYHTjO6J4u8YvTHLpXzY4n7DrKJ8l2qsawyds6ubTDS5gfVMIMAZqLIUyb/IBI9EHkmaHkksBGL4Ag)

#### How?

We use the following template:

```
 _/|2
|  |\0
|_ |/1
  \|3
```

If \$n=0\$ (volume muted):

- \$0\$ is replaced with `/` and \$1\$ is replaced with `\`
- the other digits are removed

If \$n\neq 0\$:

- odd digits are replaced with the string `" /"` repeated \$k\$ times
- even digits are replaced with the string `" \"` repeated \$k\$ times

where \$k\$ is defined as:

$$k=\cases{\left\lfloor n/33\right\rfloor&\text{$n<99$}\\
2&\text{$n\ge 99$}
}$$

Comment: for 99 and 100, output has an unnecessary line

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks for reporting this. Now fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>65</s> 64 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ /SõD‚„\ Â‚D4δ∍D)T•4aÖ™é•“| 0\
1/“ÅвJrI33÷IĀ+©è‡∊'_1•uтÄ•22в®è‚ǝ
```

When I started I thought I would be able to make this pretty short with the approach I had in mind, but it had some annoying edge cases to fix.. Can definitely be golfed, though. Will take another look later on.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8Bf3gw1tdHjXMArJjFA43AVkuJue2POroddEMedSwyCTx8LRHLYsOrwSyHzXMqVEwiOEy1AeyDrde2ORV5GlsfHi755EG7UMrD6941LDwUUeXerwhUK1@CNAQoJampgubDq0Dyc06Pvf/fwMA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6fx/1DBPQT/48FaXRw2zgOwYhcNNQJaLybktjzp6XTRDHjUsMkk8PO1Ry6LDK4HsRw1zahQMYrgM9YGsw60XNnkVVRobH95eeaRB@9DKwyseNSx81NGlHm8IVKsfAjQEqKWp6cKmQ@tAcrOOz/2vc2ib/f9oAx1DHWMjHWNjHWMTHTNTHTMzHTNzHUsLHUtLHUMDg1gA).

**Explanation:**

```python
„ /              # Push string " /"
   S             # Convert it to a list of characters: [" ","/"]
õD‚              # Push an empty string "", duplicate it, and pair them together: ["",""]
„\               # Push string "\ "
   Â             # Bifurcate it (shorter for duplicate and reverse copy)
    ‚            # Pair them together: ["\ ","\ "]
D                # Duplicate it
 4δ∍             # Extend both inner strings to size 4: ["\ \ ","\ \ "]
D                # Duplicate it
)                # Wrap all lists on the stack into a list:
                 #  [[" ","/"],["",""],["\ ","\ "],["\ \ ","\ \ "],["\ \ ","\ \ "]]
T                # Push 10
•4aÖ™é•          # Push compressed integer 17523821317
“| 0\
1/“              # Push string "| 0\\n1/"
   Åв            # Convert the integer to custom base-"| 0\\n1/" 
     J           # And join these characters together to a single string:
                 #  "  /| 1\n
                 #   |  |\0"
r                # Reverse the items on the stack (list, 10, string to string, 10, list)
 I33÷            # Push the input, and integer-divide it by 33
     IĀ          # Push the input again, and truthy it (0 if 0; else 1)
       +         # And add them together (0→0; 1..32→1; 33..65→2; 66..98→3; 98..100→4)
        ©        # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
         è       # And index it into the list we created at the start
          ‡      # Then transliterate the ["1","0"] of 10 to the strings in this pair
∊                # Now vertically mirror the entire string
                 #  (i.e. "  /|  \n
                 #         |  |\/" becomes:
                 #   "  /|  \n
                 #    |  |\/\n
                 #    |  |/\\n
                 #      \|  "
    •/Tδ•        # Push compressed integer 7095187
         ₂в      # Converted to base-26 as list: [15,13,17,21,21]
           ®     # Push variable `®` again
            è    # Index it into this list
   1         ‚   # Pair it with a leading 1
 '_           ǝ '# And insert a "_" at those 0-based positions inside the string
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•4aÖ™é•` is `17523821317`; `•/Tδ•` is `7095187`,  and `•/Tδ•₂в` is `[15,13,17,21,21]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> <s>101</s> 90 bytes

```python
n=input()
for s in'\ _/|','\|  |\/','/|_ |/\\','/  \|':print s[1:6+0**n],s[:n>32],s[:n/66]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc2xCsIwEIDh/Z7i6BKthaQJ3lCoizr7AE3pIBWzXEMbQeHePba6fcMPf/yk58Q2n2@XazsXRZG5DRxfabeHxzTjgoGVx0GLqpQXRPF6lZYBRXu/EdGLauIcOOHS1Q0dTFlyXy1dwydn/9BEff41sE5gfI933J4lZQPOgnNARyCC2pgv)

<sub>-11 bytes, thanks to xnor</sub>

Comment: Nice method! I found a way to shorten it by encoding `b` in the first character of each string rather than as a zip, and extracting from there: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc2xCsIwEIDh/Z7i6BKthaQJ3lCoizr7AE3pIBWzXEMbQeHePba6fcMPf/yk58Q2n2@XazsXRZG5DRxfabeHxzTjgoGVx0GLqpQXRPF6lZYBRXu/EdGLauIcOOHS1Q0dTFlyXy1dwydn/9BEff41sE5gfI933J4lZQPOgnNARyCC2pgv "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Wow nice! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>308 259 246 242 219</s> 180 bytes

```lua
i=io.read("*n")
print(i<1 and[[ _/|
|  |\/
|_ |/\
  \|]]or i<33 and[[ _/|
|  |\
|_ |/
  \|]]or i<66 and[[ _/| \
|  |\ \
|_ |/ /
  \| /]]or[[ _/| \ \
|  |\ \ \
|_ |/ / /
  \| / /]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxCoAgFAXQ3a@4NGVDEoFTfUlGCDU8CA2p7f27EVZGZz7rYWOknnwdFjuXReUKKbZAbi@pa2DdPAyYFAsG2CjBE1gZARgeRx9AXdv@V0rfo3U@MGnhfkgT6rpPySm3N15Vxqj1CQ)

New to code golf and coding in general.

Thanks to all comments for their help!

Comment: Hey, quick tip: the input is guaranteed to be within $[0, 100]$ so you don't need to check that it is less than 101. Also your third line doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Third line? Edited now so may be different, but all were necessary excluding the 100/0 input check..

Comment: yes my comment was made before your edit :) Anyways, you are still unnecessarily checking for $i<101$, when it is guaranteed that $i<101$.

Comment: You can replace `i==0` with `i<1`

Comment: do `p=print` to shorten it

Comment: also use `[[long strings like this to not escape \ and newlines]]`

Comment: Use "if-expressions" in order to golf your code. [(Shorter than the existing Lua solution!)](https://tio.run/##XcqxCoAgFAXQ3a@4NGVDEoFTfUlGCDU8CA2p7f27EVZGZz7rYWOknnwdFjuXReUKKbZAbi@pa2DdPAyYFAsG2CjBE1gZARgeRx9AXdv@V0rfo3U@MGnhfkgT6rpPySm3N15Vxqj1CQ "Lua – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh, I forgot about or/and's other uses. Explanation for people uneducated: Lua's `or` returns the first argument if true, the second if false - the opposite is true for `and`.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 113 bytes

```powershell
param($n)' _/|'+($y=' \'*($x=($n-ge33)+($n-ge66)))
'|  |\'+($y,'/')[!$n]
'|_ |/'+(($z=' /'*$x),'\')[!$n]
"  \|$z"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNCsIwEITveYq1LG62rUQM5JYnMVJ6SPVQa6kH@xOfPYYULzPDN8OMr4@f3g/f9xE7u4k4tlP7lDgwQaMCVRIXS@ColDjbxE93rzVXezKGmQUFgODytCZFfD3gcEu0gaASlbimB0UlzlyT@/cFgAu4FlF8hThiB@es@rKbzmZM/AE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 86 bytes

inspired from @Arnauld's solution

```perl
$_=' _/|3
|  |\\1
|_ |/0
  \|2'=~s,\d,$_?" $&"x($_/33-$_/99):$&<2&&$&^1,ger;y;0213;//\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczfCoIwFIDx@/MUBxmzYLY/B0e2pCfoDUYjSEQQHepFwejRW958v7svdstY58xCW2KQiSAhJu81pIBJKkD0yZTtdxX@JVi4Fch48T6wIImqvU1zvDB@NZwz/tCi7xb3ccpoclL6nBVoIANEYGuwFpozaKV@c9yGeVpzNT5jru71SemdYdq6ffAH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
ＮθＦ AＦ›θ℅ι \Ｃ¹¦¹⸿\Ｆ¬θ/‖Ｍ↓⸿←Ｐ↑⁴←↖¹←_↑² _/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITvPsWSUwIVW/FUT6Iggq1F8FYotaYYiElc0opPH5vWn@Jtdr@Z2a2uJVa6lM7tlGls2tzOHOmdLSe1RqAEVoRBL7fIS@tZAAe8CFVKKhhjkKFQtjPmOelSa22eNAog6vSb5DigviXVtmv/pmYeHHkteWUTgaiRxhv9UOO0tyS65TTe89r6oZFWmB7HJxPA4t@QfZifx7/Ew4IUZOwKYP67B4X/ybkoDN20lS8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the volume.

```
Ｆ AＦ›θ℅ι \
```

Output a space and a `\` for each character ordinal in space and `A` that the volume is greater than. In other words, output once for inputs of 33 or more and twice for inputs of 66 or more.

```
Ｃ¹¦¹
```

Copy the `\`s one square diagonally.

```
⸿\
```

Output an extra `\` at the start of the second line.

```
Ｆ¬θ/
```

If the volume was zero then add a `/`.

```
‖Ｍ↓
```

Reflect to complete the volume.

```
⸿←Ｐ↑⁴←↖¹←_↑² _/
```

Draw the speaker symbol.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>94</s> 92 bytes

```powershell
param($n)33,66-le$n|%{$y+=' \';$z+=' /'}
" _/|$y
|  |\$y"+'/'*!$n
"|_ |/$z"+'\'*!$n
"  \|$z"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjBCsIwEITh@z7FGkajVokYyEX6JoHSQ4qHGEs9SNrts8davcw/fP3zHYbXPcRY0NUTlb4d2sce6WDtyblzDEiynZCrWrPXN4zfY/RMihsjyCTM4pFVpY0@bpBIScNiMC7i/8LsZYFCM9EOHV/Wtddf7Brnygc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>32</s> <s>27</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
┤＃Mi‾‟⁸？⁸‾｛÷ｕ２ｍ２＼×＋］ ¶/＋｝═
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTI0JXVGRjAzTWkldTIwM0UldTIwMUYldTIwNzgldUZGMUYldTIwNzgldTIwM0UldUZGNUIlRjcldUZGNTUldUZGMTIldUZGNEQldUZGMTIldUZGM0MlRDcldUZGMEIldUZGM0QlMjAlQjYvJXVGRjBCJXVGRjVEJXUyNTUw,i=MzM_,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hd` 167 bytes

```
¿:0=[` _/|\n|  |\\/\n|_ |/\\\n  \\|`|:1\!"∂[` _/|\n|  |\\\n|_ |/\n  \\|`|:\!B"∂[` _/| \\\n|  |\\ \\\n|_ |/ /\n  \\| /`|` _/| \\ \\\n|  |\\ \\ \\\n|_ |/ / /\n  \\| / /`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0H4rA9voBIV4/ZqYvBoFhZqYGH0gI16hRj8mJiZPQSEmpiahxsowRlHpUUcTqkKYOriqGEUnhCoFsAKwQgW4WgWYagX9hBqYMlSVyIqRlAM1/P9vZvZfNyMFAA)

Definitely golfable by using variables and string formatting. That's what Imma go do now. Anyhow, it acts as a sort of switch statement to determine which range the volume is in and prints the corresponding string.

Nevermind. Variables only make the program longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 109 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(i[:5+0**n]+(n//33*(' '+j))[:4]for i,j in zip([' _/|','|  |\\/','|_ |/\\','  \|'],'\\\//'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoMwEADvfcXeNolLE5uaQ6AvcUUsJTRSVxEvLfm71dvAzCzf7T2L39OD988wPV8DSEQWvI5zFpXb2FTOGOkqJdZ6bxQCVqPWbbx3aV4h0whZ4JcX1SL0tiBhASjM9qQeimU@CIALdoR8CIta7@cs5@qoJn8j7yk0FALVzsULLGuWTSUlR/oH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 196 bytes

```lua
i=tonumber(io.read())
t=[[ _/|%s
|  |\%s
|_ |/%s
  \|%s]]
t=(i==0 and t:format("","/","\\","")) or t
while i>=33 do t=t:format(" \\%s"," \\%s"," /%s"," /%s");i=i-34 end
t=t:gsub("%%s","")
print(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEEX3OcUQKCSgRqgoKPEiTSktiTrQJpJOcZO7x9SFXcx/8Hl/xqXPGTUFv0yDiwLDIbreCikZ6aaBTqVqZgkgmZUdJFUIYErdtsURqPURem@Bro8Qp54E5zuuyhlTgksJIQKxzwtHB3jXdQ02AOnNB1OeF/dPtUHeUOO@PoHzlq2j57wMglc/g0v2juhJkMz5fPkC)

A bit shorter (below 200) than the [other Lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195519/63068).