# Draw an ASCII Volume

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a volume level `V` in the range `1-10`. Your program should draw the following ASCII art.

When `V=1`:

```
\
 |
/
```

When `V=2`:

```
  \
\  |
 | |
/  |
  /
```

When `V=3`:

```
    \
  \  |
\  | |
 | | |
/  | |
  /  |
    /
```

And etc. Trailing spaces are allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: [Similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195504/84844)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>169</s> <s>157</s> <s>144</s> <s>131</s> <s>98</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> 87 bytes

*Thanks [@ophact](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106710/ophact) for helping me save <s>some</s> a lot of bytes*

*Thanks [@alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha) for helping me golf it down to under 100 bytes with a completely new strategy*

*Thanks [@
emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a) for another -8 bytes*

```python
lambda n:[print(*" "*~-abs(i)+(i!=0)*"\\/"[i>0],(n-abs(i))*" |")for i in range(-n,n+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKrqgKDOvRENLSUFJq043MalYI1NTWyNT0dZAU0spJkZfKTrTziBWRyMPKgcUVahR0kzLL1LIVMjMUyhKzEtP1dDN08nTNtSM/Y8mbqhjaKhpxaUAsSRTk0shDUxC@Jr/AQ)

<s>First time trying to golf in Python. There's probably tons of stuff to golf here :D</s>

My answer has literally been golfed to death entirely by the efforts of other people (not me).

Comment: [149 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7NCoMwEITvPsV2T9n4U6KXIvgk6kFq0m6RNQQPLfTd01ihh14GhplvGP/a7qs0Fx9inK0Dp4TaDJauR0Ctai1lXdaa80Yr7johynEYYM/4lGzOGt@Abg3AwAJhkptVkhsa00pln5uVWXEVrF@mq1UJxgLPSD9i6cu6bUszUgY@sGypI1g9Vha1EMW/aVMYsz88qpwg99XDU/wA) For the future: use list comprehensions, remove spaces, use operators in such a way that you can remove spaces around the expressions (for instance, no space needed between a string literal and a keyword).

Comment: @ophact thanks for the tips!

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYuxDsIgFEV3vwLfxINSA10MCV9SOqC2@kx9JaSLif@OddDB7Zzce/JzvS3cHXOpU4h1To/TJQn2EBna@0Is5exDDwKUdIqNM06R7pSkEBhRQ4zis9F@U00KXgKmpQgSxKIkvo6StcUBdU9tGfOczqPcImjgAPh7zr1x3hs7DFj/cttYi34nciFeJeGXpo1/gvUN) by switching to lambda and making use of python's `:=` (walrus) operator. The lambda mode is usually much shorter than `def... [...] return ...`

Comment: @ophact Thanks for letting me know about lambda, I wasn't really aware of what it is.

Comment: [98 bytes porting my PARI/GP answer](https://tio.run/##XYw7DsIwDIZ3TmF5itsGiFhQVbgIYUgFAaPWiUIXJO4eUlAXtu9/xtd0D7Lbx5T9webBjf3FgbRoBdePwKJOCICVcv1TMWlDNVo7G9xtC2@@eCyoRP86VCG80YcEDCyQnNyuSksjtaEz5b/ANMZQu4KYWKayXsjPT4ug/AE "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online").

Comment: @alephalpha Not even too sure how that works but that's amazing

Comment: @alephalpha [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcY5CoAwEADA3leErXIQvDrN@hKbCIILsgaNiCB@PQanmnDHZeMmJUbicEapCsKXi2uhdRbkuCODde/RT4ck1YedOIIQoF/rDYw5klylDJR/h1zJ1isN4oGU2g8) as full program in Python 2.

Comment: @ovs ok what, i just edited my answer and now this... wow. I don't even know what `~` does...

Comment: `~` flips all bits in the binary representation of an integer. Because of the way negative integers are represented (2s complement) this result in `-n-1`. [See this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37553/64121)

Comment: i'm not sure if I should even edit this in, it's basically not even my answer anymore...

Comment: @ovs That's very interesting, good to know about that.

Comment: @ovs you should make that your own answer, python2 is technically different language from python3.8

Comment: [87](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKrqgKDOvRENLSUFJq043MalYI1NTWyNT0dZAU0spJkZfKTrTziBWRyMPKgcUVahR0kzLL1LIVMjMUyhKzEtP1dDN08nTNtSM/Y8mbqhjaKhpxaUAsSRTk0shDUxC@Jr/AQ)

Comment: @ophact thanks, this really isn't even my answer anymore...

Comment: Don't get demotivated, use this as a learning experience. If you decide to continue golfing in Python, you can use all the tips we've taught you.

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 17 bytes

```
ɾ\|*\\?ɾ꘍$YvøMøĊ§
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvlxcfCpcXFxcP8m+6piNJFl2w7hNw7jEisKnIiwiIiwiMyJd)

This was quite a nice approach that may have ended up a bit clunky due to lack of overloads.

The idea is simple: Create the rotated form:

```
  \ /
   |
 \   /
  |||
\     /
 |||||
```

And rotate it 90° with the `§` builtin.

We can create the above by interleaving the following:

```
   |
  |||
 |||||

  \ /
 \   /
\     /
```

And that's basically what this does, with a few convenient Vyxal builtins. So close to beating Charcoal...

```
   *              # Repeat...
 \|               # "|"
ɾ                 # By 1...n
      ?ɾ          # 1...n
        ꘍         # Spaces appended to...
    \\            # "\" 
         $Y       # Interleave them
           vøM    # Mirror each line, leaving the middle alone and flipping slashes
              øĊ  # Align each line to the center
                § # Rotate the whole thing 90°
```

Comment: Excellent character choice for the rotation operator in vyxal

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
n=i=input()
while~n-i:x=abs(i);print('  '*x+'\/'[i<0]+' ')[2:],'| '*(n-x);i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8820zYzr6C0REOTqzwjMye1Lk8306rCNjGpWCNT07qgKDOvRENdQUFdq0JbPUZfPTrTxiBWW11BXTPayCpWR70GKKORp1uhaZ2pa2v4/78xAA)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

This builds the output character per character. (So it may be longer than generating the strings explicitly, but it's a little more fun. ^^)

```javascript
n=>(y=n,g=x=>y<-n?'':` |\\/
`[d=y*y-x*x++/4,x>n*2?(y--,x=0,4):x&1?d-x?0:2^y<0:d<0|0]+g(x))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZchLDoIwEADQPadwJR1opXxWDUMPIpoSCkRDWiPGTBPuXteGt3zP4Tts4/vx@gjn7RRnjA47FtDxBQm70Aqn01SZ0973RWKuFkMWBGWU50XDqXNZpVkQghNK3oCic6mtIC1VdQ@tVLaVu7zlCyMAY@Lo3ebX6bL6hc2sBEj@pzpMfZgGIP4A)

#### How?

For each position \$(x,y)\$ with \$0\le x<2n\$ and \$-n\le y \le n\$, we compute:

$$d=y^2-x^2/4$$

For \$n=3\$, this gives:

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline
& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
3 & 9 & 8.75 & 8 & 6.75 & \color{red}{5} & 2.75 \\ \hline
2 & 4 & 3.75 & \color{red}{3} & 1.75 & 0 & \color{blue}{-2.25} \\ \hline
1 & \color{red}{1} & 0.75 & 0 & \color{blue}{-1.25} & -3 & \color{blue}{-5.25} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-0.25} & -1 & \color{blue}{-2.25} & -4 & \color{blue}{-6.25} \\ \hline
-1 & \color{red}{1} & 0.75 & 0 & \color{blue}{-1.25} & -3 & \color{blue}{-5.25} \\ \hline
-2 & 4 & 3.75 & \color{red}{3} & 1.75 & 0 & \color{blue}{-2.25} \\ \hline
-3 & 9 & 8.75 & 8 & 6.75 & \color{red}{5} & 2.75 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We then apply the following rules:

- If \$x\$ is even:

  - If \$x=d-1\$, we insert either a `\` or a `/` according to the sign of \$y\$ (red cells)
  - Otherwise, we insert a space
- If \$x\$ is odd:

  - If \$d<0\$, we insert a `|` (blue cells)
  - Otherwise, we insert a space

Comment: +1 for the math part!

Answer (score 6):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 85 bytes

```
n->for(i=-n,n,print(concat([if(j>l=abs(i)," |",j<l,"  ",i<0,"\\ ","/ ")|j<-[1..n]])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoMwDEDRq1iebMmhoK4JFwGGFCnIETJRysjd03R7@sMvsao7SksQmrk5XZU0OBOTUtVu2i/b402LJsrzGeLnS8qC8KBkf3YAivpRcF278AXIT/ZumYbBto2Z239pEGASeAskst5@)

Comment: Wow how does this even work

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->n{(-n..n).map{|c|((" "*2*z=c.abs)+(c>0?"/ ":"\\ ")+" |"*n)[2,2*n]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAryx7UksLoUugPaQ8qOCtJbIOpb3dZs47PC2ZJi0VJkkp4mr3R6mxMoaAQovXROVD5h2LdlxwAJxx2wB5h1BREF91rwW572vHfWVI6@TaDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＦＮ«Ｐ↖²Ｐ↓⊕ι→↗»‖Ｂ↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqL07c0pySzoCgzr0TDKrTAJzWtREfBSNMaVcIlvzxPR8EzL7koNTc1ryQ1RSNTE6wmvyxVwyooMz2jBMENLYAJ1HIFpablpCaXOJWWlKQWpeVUQozStP7/3/i/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop `V` times.

```
Ｐ↖²
```

Draw each of the `\`s along the top as a line of two without moving the cursor, so that the second one gets overwritten by the vertical line below.

```
Ｐ↓⊕ι
```

Draw the top half of each vertical line without moving the cursor.

```
→↗
```

Move to the top of the next vertical line.

```
»‖Ｂ↓
```

Reflect to complete the art.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ýx¨R'\ús„ |×ζ`θ».∊
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8OdeMKoUidcw7pz4oCeIHzDl862YM64wrsu4oiK//8z) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4/T88t@LQiiD1mMO7ih81zFOoOTz93LaEczsO7dZ71NH1X@fQNvv/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
          #  e.g. input=3
Ý         # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3]
 x        # Double each value (without popping)
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3],[0,2,4,6]
  ¨       # Remove the last item
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3],[0,2,4]
   R      # Reverse it
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3],[4,2,0]
    '\   '# Push string "\"
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3],[4,2,0],"\"
      ú   # Pad it with leading spaces based on the integer-list
          #  STACK: [0,1,2,3],["    \","  \","\"]
 s        # Swap so the earlier list is at the top
          #  STACK: ["    \","  \","\"],[0,1,2,3]
  „ |     # Push string " |"
          #  STACK: ["    \","  \","\"],[0,1,2,3]," |"
     ×    # Repeat it the integers amount of times
          #  STACK: ["    \","  \","\"],[""," |"," | |"," | | |"]
       ζ  # Create pairs of the two lists, which uses a space as implicit filler
          # since they're of unequal lengths
          #  STACK: [["    \",""],["  \"," |"],["\"," | |"],[" "," | | |"]]
`         # Pop and push the pairs separated to the stack
          #  STACK: ["    \",""],["  \"," |"],["\"," | |"],[" "," | | |"]
 θ        # Leave just the last/second item of the top pair
          #  STACK: ["    \",""],["  \"," |"],["\"," | |"]," | | |"
  »       # Join the stack with newline delimiter, which will implicitly join
          # lists by spaces first
          #  STACK: "    \ \n  \  |\n\  | |\n | | |"
   .∊     # Vertically mirror with overlap
          #  STACK: "    \ \n  \  |\n\  | |\n | | |\n\  | |\n  \  |\n    \ "
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>241</strike>, 238 bytes

```
public class V{public static void main(String[]a){int V=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt(),d=-1,i=V;var s="";while(i<=V){if(i==0)d=1;else s+=("  ".repeat(i-1)+(d<0?"\\ ":"/ "));s+=" |".repeat(V-i)+'\n';i+=d;}System.out.print(s);}}
```

Obviously Java is a rather verbose language for code golf, but I like to see how well I can do with it anyway.
It isn't clear if "Given a value V" means to read it as an input, or if the value for V is allowed to be hard coded, so long as values in the range (1-10) work.
If the value for V can be set in the code, the answer can be reduced to 198 bytes.

If we go so far as to allow a line of code that can be entered into jshell, then we can get it to 145 or 146 bytes (depending on V being one or two digits):

```
int V=3,d=-1,i=V;var s="";while(i<=V){if(i==0)d=1;else s+=("  ".repeat(i-1)+(d<0?"\\ ":"/ "));s+=" |".repeat(V-i)+'\n';i+=d;}System.out.print(s);
```

In this case the input value for V is entered directly in the program. I suspect this violates [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) though.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! Hard-coding input in a variable isn't typically allowed here, yeah. (It's perfectly fine to include both versions like you do now though)

Comment: You could shove off another 86 characters from the class-based solution by using a lambda (Java 8+): `(int V)->{int d=-1,i=V;var s="";while(i<=V){if(i==0)d=1;else s+=("  ".repeat(i-1)+(d<0?"\\ ":"/ "));s+=" |".repeat(V-i)+'\n';i+=d;}System.out.print(s);}`

Comment: @Muskovets Only if I don't submit a complete program.  If I need to read V from stdin, make a complete runnable program, the lambda is actually more bytes than my comparable last code snippet.

Comment: @swpalmer The rules did say you *can* submit a function instead of a runnable program last time I checked.. Look at the JS, Ruby, etc. answers, they all use lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

## GNU APL, <s>43</s> 42 Chars, <s>67</s> 66 Bytes

```
{⍉(2/-⍵-⍳⍵)⌽⊃⊃,/{1(¯1+2×⍵)1/¨"\ /"" | "}¨⍳⍵}
```

`⊃⊃,/{1(¯1+2×⍵)1/¨'\ /' ' | '}¨⍳⍵` replicates characters according to the input and builds the matrix, for example V=3:

```
\ /    
 |     
\   /  
 |||   
\     /
 |||||
```

`(2/-⍵-⍳⍵)⌽` rotates rows to their position, and finally `⍉` does a transpose:

```
    \ 
  \  |
\  | |
 | | |
/  | |
  /  |
    /
```

Update:

Since GNU APL support double quote string, `'\ /' ' | '` can be rewritten as `"\ /"" | "`, with one space removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
.+
$*:¶$&$*:¶$&$*:
:
 |
\G \|
¶$.%'$* \ $%`
r` \|\G
$.%`$* / $%'¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRcvq0DYVNQTFZcWlUMMV464QU8MFFNJTVVfRUohRUFFN4CpKAArGuHMBBROAgvpAQfVD2/7/NwYA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*:¶$&$*:¶$&$*:
```

Convert the input into three rows of `V` `:`s as placeholders for the `|`s (which cost an extra byte to match).

```
:
 |
```

Replace the `:`s with  `|`, so that the `|`s have the correct spacing.

```
\G \|
¶$.%'$* \ $%`
```

Turn the first row of  `|`s into a "triangle", preceded with `\`s.

```
r` \|\G
$.%`$* / $%'¶
```

Turn the last row of  `|`s into a "triangle", preceded with `/`s.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 59 bytes

Prompts for n. Index origin = 0

```
(∊2/¨⌽-i)⊖⍉⊃,('\',¨(-1+n)↑¨'/'),[0.1]' ',¨(n←1+2×i←⍳⎕)⍴¨'|'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv8ajji4j/UMrHvXs1c3UfNQ17VFv56OuZh0N9Rh1nUMrNHQNtfM0H7VNPLRCXV9dUyfaQM8wVl0BLJUHNMVQ2@jw9Ewg41HvZqDJmo96twBV1qj/BxrO9T@Ny5ALqJgrjcsIShtzAQA)